# How do I stack the color planes of multiple images and run inference on that?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, image-resizing

as a part of my project, i choosed remote sensing and deep learning topic.
I obtained few images using remote sensing techniques and loaded them into the colab.
[image: image shape]

The above picture describes the shape of each image

Now my model requires it in different format as it is trained on
[image: image size requirement]

where 3039 denotes the number of training samples.
so i have to change (2583,1900),(2411,2571),(2583,1900),(2583,1900,3) into a single array with dimensions (1,128,128,6)

The problem is how do i make 3 one-dimensional arrays and 1 three-dimensional arrays into 1 six-dimensional array.

How do i do it.
Please help me.

Comment: maybe you can explain, what your model does, and what it is for ? (it seems to *generate* another, 1 channel image ?

Comment: are those images **aligned**? you first have to align them, so they're all the same size _and_ features in the images _align_. don't blindly try to stack them. **show us** those pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first resize the arrays to 128x128, then concat them along the last dim:

```
x = np.concatenate((
    np.resize(dem,(1,128,128,1)),
    np.resize(slope,(1,128,128,1)),
    np.resize(nvdi,(1,128,128,1)),
    np.resize(rgb,(1,128,128,3))), -1)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when executing your code
''ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data''
How do i solve this

Comment: apologies, my bad, it cant be done in-place. try edited version, please.

Comment: np.resize would be ill advised. it does not resample data. it literally truncates or extends an array. -- `cv.resize` is required, if you need to resample the images.